# I'm Using Wp-Page Navi But Its Dont Show the second page

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="VideoArea">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <?php
  $myposts = array(
      'showposts' => 5,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'orderby' => 'date',
  );
  $wp_query= null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query($myposts);
  <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="newvideoarea">
    <div class="hovervideoarea">
      <div class="title">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb">
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb'); ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?></a>
  <div class="pagination">
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is my code, Wp page navi is appearing but when I click on 2nd page it cannot show, and just returned the post. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Can someone solve my Problem ?

Comment: Any Help , ? about this topic ?